# Content serving in android

Tags: android

Though as a beginner, I am trying to develop an android app which is story based, i will like to know the best way to serve content to the user, i mean like a continuous update of content, just like updating news by the hour. As users will install just once, how will they get the latest content of my news or story based app.
I have access to domain names and hosting if it requires uploading such content through a domain.
from your experience, what is the best method to achieve this? I humbly await a response, thanks

Comment: The question isn't specific enough. What exactly do you want to do?  Do you want the users to get some updated info which requires access to the internet? On one hand you wrote 'update...latest content', on the other hand you wrote 'story based up' or 'news app'. They are all different!

Comment: i want users to be able to get the latest content on the app, you know just like a newspaper that is updated by the hour or daily, i wanted to use a website as a webview for that purpose in which the website is easily updated by me and displays as a web page in the app but it seems there is another way of updating the app content without using a webview to display pages.

Comment: I'm sorry, the question is still not concrete enough. I will give you a general answer then in about an hour or so

Comment: Simply put, considering for example you want to develop an app for a news station like CNN or Wall Street journal. how will latest news content be available to users, you as the developer, how will you achieve this? are you going to link the news content to a database whereby content can be updated and be available instantly on the various news section of the app

Answer (score 0):

So given the clarification in the comments this is the answer:

The best way is PUSHING the content to the user's device.
Generally speaking, the two ways for a new content to reach an app are :

1.polling your server (or any third-party server) for new data every,say, 20 minutes. The disadvantage of this method is that it drains the battery. Every time that the phone connects to the internet, the radio in that phone stays on (or in a standby mode) for something like 2 minutes. Those modes (on and standby) drain the battery. Another problem is that it does use data needlessly and in some countries cellular data is expensive (Canada for example).
This could be a solution if the data changes very very frequently (for example a stock's price can change many many times a day). But generally speaking method 2 is the preferred method..

2.Pushing the content to the user's phone.
Your server will send a message to the device once new data that you want to send is there (and you could also put that data in the payload of the message if it's not too much).
This means that the phone will connect only when some new data is available.
Saves battery life,and gets the information as soon as it is available!
I recommend using GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) for this purpose which is free, and simple to use. If you have no idea how to do that in Android (which is likely since you said that you are a beginner), it is explained really well in Udacity's 
Advanced Android App Development. It is a free course by Udacity and Google, but the section about GCM is only about 15 minutes long.

If you know how to implement a server but don't know how to use GCM in your server (and you don't find Google's documentation helpful) do let me know..
If you don't know how to implement a server...well then it's something you will have to learn in order to get your content to your users as that's the best way.

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you for your help and reply, however I don't mean push notifications, all I want to achieve is say for example, you write in your diary everyday and that text is what you to keep updating, how do you go about this? I mean updating the text content of an activity remotely just like adding new content to your blog or website so that users can read the lates . After deploying your app to the play store,  I assume one cannot edit the text in the app and keep resubmitting, that is the logic i am looking for. I heard one can connect android to php, mysql and json to edit text in d app remotely

Comment: OK, How do you expect to transfer that information? It has to go through the internet. From your computer to their device. Your computer = server. What worries me is "I heard one can connect android to php, mysql and json to edit text in d app remotely". See, PHP is a language,mysql is a dialect of SQL (database language), json is a format (java script object notation). You can implement your server using PHP,sure... Connect android to PHP is a meaningless sentence though. It's like saying connect my desktop to java. Why won't you show me that source of information if that needs clarification?

Comment: Ok then, as i said earlier, i am new at this so forgive my ignorance. Lets do it this way, assuming you want to develop an app for CNN where they will be able to update the content themselves, what will be your plan if you could give me steps on all that is required to achieve this,i will be glad

Comment: As I said: 1. Implement a server-side app capable of sending GCM messages 2.On the android app add the logic to accept GCM messages(push notifications). You have plenty of documentation and tutorial regarding both part 1 and part 2...